# Problema con Login y Routas Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy autenticando usuario con ADLDAP usando el paquete: https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2

La autenticacion funciona correctamente, al menos eso creo, el problema que me esta dando es que una vez logeado, cuando clickeo sobre algún botón de menú, me envía directamente al login nuevamente, le dejo una imagen cuando logeo, la URL me coloca /login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le doy click a algún menú, como lo dije arriba, me devuelve a la pantalla de login de usuario y password.

Les copio aquí mi LoginController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected $lockoutTime;
protected $maxLoginAttempts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);

    $this->lockoutTime  = 1;    //bloqueo por 1 minuto (el valor se define en minutos)
    $this->maxLoginAttempts = 3;    //Cantidad de intentos para bloquear

}

public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}    

public function password()
{
    return 'password';
}

public function redirectPath()
{
    return '/welcome';
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $log = [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password
            ];
    try {
        \Adldap::connect();
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if (\Auth::attempt($log)) {

            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
            if(\Auth::check()){
                return view($this->redirectPath());
            }
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);         
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request); 

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return view('errors.LDAP')>with(['ldap_error' => $e>getMessage()]);
    }
 }

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.user_failed'), $this->password() => trans('auth.password_failed')];

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        >withInput($request>only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}

protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
{
    return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
        $this->throttleKey($request), $this->maxLoginAttempts, $this->lockoutTime
    );
}
```

}

Y mis rutas son estas:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('auth.login');
});
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::get('/welcome', ['as'=>'bienvenidos', 'uses' =>  function () {
    return view('welcome');
}]);

Route::get('/ordenes', ['as'=>'ordenes', 'uses'=>'OrdenesController@index']);

Route::get('ordenes/autocomplete', 'OrdenesController@autocomplete');
Route::post('ordenes/add', 'OrdenesController@addproduct');
Route::post('ordenes/totales', 'OrdenesController@totales');
Route::post('ordenes/guardar', 'OrdenesController@store');

});
```

Añado mas informacion, aqui mi layout principal:

```
<title>{{ config('app.name') }} | @yield('title') </title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- NProgress -->
<link href="assets/vendor/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Theme Style -->
<link href="assets/build/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

@yield('css')
```

```
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- menu profile quick info -->
        <div class="profile clearfix">
          <!--<div class="profile_pic">
            <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
          </div>-->
          <div class="profile_info">
            <span>Bienvenido,</span>
            <h2>{{ Auth::user()->getCommonName() }}</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /menu profile quick info -->

        <br />

        <!-- sidebar menu -->
        <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
          <div class="menu_section">
            <h3>General</h3>
            <ul class="nav side-menu">
              <li><a href="{!! route('bienvenidos') !!}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home </a></li>
              <li><a href="{!! route('ordenes') !!}"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> Ordenes </a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu_section">
            <h3>Live On</h3>
            <ul class="nav side-menu">

            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /sidebar menu -->

        <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
        <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lock">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout" href="login.html">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
      </div>
    </div> <!-- END MENU LATERAL  -->

    <!-- top navigation -->
    <div class="top_nav">
      <div class="nav_menu">
        <nav>
          <!--<div class="nav toggle">
            <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          </div>-->

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="{{ Auth::user()->getThumbnailEncoded() }}" alt="">{{ Auth::user()->getFirstName() }} {{ Auth::user()->getLastName() }}
                <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">

                <li><a href="javascript:;">Help</a></li>
                <li><a class="salir" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();                                                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit()";>
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a>
                </li>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /top navigation -->

    <!-- page content -->
    <div class="right_col" role="main">
      <div class="">
        <div class="page-title">
          <div class="title_left">
            <h3>@yield('page-title')</h3>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              @yield('content')
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /page content -->

    <!-- footer content -->
    <footer>
      <div class="pull-right">
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /footer content -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="assets/vendor/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- NProgress -->
<script src="assets/vendor/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
<script src="assets/build/js/custom.js"></script>
<!-- SECCION PARA JS PERSONALIZADOS -->
@yield('js')
```

Aqui agrego la vista del link ordenes de la imagen:

```
@extends('layouts.principal')
@section('title') Ordenes @endsection
@section('page-title')
    Ordenes
@endsection

@section('css')
    <link href="assets/build/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/build/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

@section('content') 
    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_title">
        <h2>Ordenes <small> @if(isset($encabezado)) Existe una Orden ya Cargada @endif </small></h2>
        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
          <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="x_content">
        <section class="content invoice">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 invoice-header">
                <h1>
                    <i>{!! Html::image('assets/images/image.jpg','', ['class' => 'invoice-image']) !!}</i> <small class="pull-right">Fecha: {!! Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y') !!}</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
          </div>
          <!-- info row -->
          <div class="row invoice-info">
            <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
              From
                <address>
                    <strong>{!! config('app.name') !!} </strong>
                    <br>Av. Santa Fé, 2755
                    <br>Buenos Aires, CABA, Argentina
                    <br>Phone: 
                    <br>Email: 
                </address>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
              To
                <address>
                    <strong>{!! Auth::user()->getFirstName() !!} {!! Auth::user()->getLastName() !!}</strong>
                    <br>Contrato: {!! Auth::user()->getPhysicalDeliveryOfficeName() !!}
                    <br>Telefono: +54 (911) 7777-7777
                    <br>Departamento: {!! Auth::user()->getDepartment() !!}
                    <br>Email: {!! Auth::user()->getEmail() !!}

                </address>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
              <b>Orden N° 007612</b>
              <br>
              <br>
              <b>Order ID:</b> 4F3S8J
              <br>
              <b>Fecha de Pago:</b> 24/03/2017
              <br>
              <b>Contrato:</b> {!! Auth::user()->getPhysicalDeliveryOfficeName() !!}
              <br>
              <b>Campaña N°: </b> {!! $CampActual !!}
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <form id="add_product" name="add_product">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-10" for="first-name">Buscar Producto </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ui-widget">
                            <input type="text" id="productos" name="productos" required="required" class="form-control col-md-5 col-xs-10" placeholder="Buscar Productos">
                            <div class=""><i id="loadicon" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
                                <div class="has-error" id="error-productos">
                                    <span >
                                        <small id="error-productos_mensaje" class="help-block error-span" ></small>
                                    </span>
                                </div><!-- ERROR -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="cantidad_p" name="cantidad_p" required="required" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-8" placeholder="Cantidad">
                                <div class="has-error" id="error-cantidad_p">
                                    <span >
                                        <small id="error-cantidad_p_mensaje" class="help-block error-span" ></small>
                                    </span>
                                </div><!-- ERROR -->                                
                        </div>

                            <input type="hidden" id="codigo_p" name="codigo_p" class="">
                            <input type="hidden" id="descri_p" name="descri_p" class="">
                            <input type="hidden" id="precio_p" name="precio_p" class="">
                            <input type="text" id="json" class="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="num_p" name="num_p" class=""> 


                        <input type="button" name="agregar" id="agregar" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-success">
                        <input type="button" name="editar" id="editar" value="Editar" class="btn btn-warning" style="display:none">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 table">
                @if(!isset($encabezado)) 
                    <div id="order"></div>
                @else

                    <table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th class="center">Precio/U</th>
                    <th class="center">Subtotal</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr></thead><tbody>
                        @foreach($detalles as $detalle)
                        <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>{!! $detalle['codigo'] !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $detalle['descripcion'] !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $detalle['cantidad'] !!}</td>
                                    <td class="right">{!! $detalle['precio_unidad'] !!}</td>
                                    <td class="right">{!! $detalle['subtotal_item'] !!}</td>
                                    <td class="center">
                                        <a href="javascript:editar('+item.codigo+','+num+')"><label class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></label></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:cleaner('+num+')"><label class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></label></a>
                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody></table>
                @endif
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <p class="lead">Fecha de Pago 24/03/2017</p>
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <tbody>

                    <tr>
                      <th>Total:</th>
                      <td class="center"><span id="total">0.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row no-print">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.print();"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir</button>
              <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="send_orden" id="send_orden"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> Enviar Orden</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Generar PDF</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('js')
    <script src="assets/build/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/build/js/helpers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#loadicon").hide();
            $("#send_orden").attr("disabled","disabled");

            var datos_orden = '';
            localStorage.removeItem('json_save');
            if( $("#json").val() != null ){
                $("#json").val(localStorage.getItem("json_save"));
                console.log(localStorage.getItem("json_save"));
                invoice($("#json").val());
                $("#send_orden").removeAttr("disabled","");
            }

            $("#productos").autocomplete({

                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "ordenes/autocomplete",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: {
                        pagesize: 10,
                        term : request.term
                      },
                      success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                      }
                    });
                },
                search: function () {
                    $('#loadicon').show();
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#codigo_p').val(ui.item.id);
                    $('#descri_p').val(ui.item.value.trim());
                    $('#precio_p').val(ui.item.price);
                },
                response: function(event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.content.length) {
                        var noResult = { value:"",label:"No se encontraron resultados" };
                        ui.content.push(noResult);
                    } 
                    $('#loadicon').hide();
                }                   
            });

            $('#agregar').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var existe = false;
                data = $.parseJSON('{"datos": ['+$("#json").val()+']}');
                $.each(data.datos, function(i, item){
                    if(item.codigo == $("#codigo_p").val()){
                        alert('Este codigo de producto ya esta agregado');
                        existe = true;
                    }
                });

                if(existe == false){
                    var token = $('input:hidden[name=_token]').val();
                    var datos = $("#add_product").serialize();
                    limpiarMensaje();
                    add_agg_product(token,datos);
                }
            });

            $("#editar").on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var token = $('input:hidden[name=_token]').val();
                var datos = $("#add_product").serialize();
                add_agg_product(token,datos);
            });

            $("#send_orden").on('click',function(){
                detalle = '{"datos": ['+$("#json").val()+']}';
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ordenes/guardar',
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input:hidden[name=_token]').val() },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { orden_p : escape(detalle)  },
                    success: function(respuesta){
                        alert(respuesta.mensaje);
                    },
                    error:function(msj){
                        //Valido los Errores y los muestro en pantalla
                        if(msj.responseJSON.status=="ERROR"){
                          //errores(msj.responseJSON.errores);
                          alert(msj.responseJSON.mensaje);
                        }
                    }                       
                });
            });
        });


        function add_agg_product(token,datos) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ordenes/add',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: datos,
                success:function(respuesta){
                    //Valido la respuesta del Controlador
                    if(respuesta.status == 'OK'){

                        if($("#num_p").val() == ''){
                            if ($('#json').val()!=''){
                                data_j = $('#json').val()+',';
                                data_j = data_j + JSON.stringify(respuesta.info);
                                $('#json').val(data_j);

                            }else{
                                $('#json').val( JSON.stringify(respuesta.info) );
                            }
                        }else{
                            //Editamos el string JSON
                            data = $.parseJSON('{"datos": ['+$("#json").val()+']}');
                            data.datos[$("#num_p").val()-1].cantidad = respuesta.info.cantidad;
                            data.datos[$("#num_p").val()-1].subtotal_item = respuesta.info.subtotal_item;
                            $("#json").val(JSON.stringify(data).substring(10, ((JSON.stringify(data).length)-2)));
                            $("#order").removeClass('disabledbutton');

                        }
                        localStorage.setItem("json_save", $("#json").val()); 
                        invoice($("#json").val());
                        $("#productos").val("");
                        $("#codigo_p").val("");
                        $("#descri_p").val("");
                        $("#precio_p").val("");
                        $("#cantidad_p").val("");
                        $("#num_p").val("");
                        $("#productos").focus();
                        $("#send_orden").removeAttr("disabled","");
                        $("#agregar").show();
                        $("#editar").hide();
                    }

                },
                error:function(msj){
                    //Valido los Errores y los muestro en pantalla
                    if(msj.responseJSON.status=="ERROR"){
                      errores(msj.responseJSON.errores);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        function invoice(datos){
            json = $.parseJSON('{"datos": ['+datos+']}');

                    tabla = '';
                    tabla += '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr>';
                    tabla += '<th>#</th>';
                    tabla += '<th>Codigo</th>';
                    tabla += '<th>Descripcion</th>';
                    tabla += '<th>Cantidad</th>';
                    tabla += '<th class="center">Precio/U</th>';
                    tabla += '<th class="center">Subtotal</th>';
                    tabla += '<th>Acciones</th>';
                    tabla += '</tr></thead><tbody>';
                    num=0;
                    total=0;
                    $.each( json.datos, function( i, item ) {
                        num+=1;
                        total = total + item.subtotal_item;

                        $('#total').html(number_format(total,2,',','.'));

                        tabla += '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>'+num+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+item.codigo+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+unescape(item.descripcion)+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+item.cantidad+'</td>'+
                                    '<td class="right">'+number_format(item.precio_unidad, 2, ',', '.')+'</td>'+
                                    '<td class="right">'+number_format(item.subtotal_item, 2, ',', '.')+'</td>'+
                                    '<td class="center">'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:editar('+item.codigo+','+num+')"><label class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></label></a>'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:cleaner('+num+')"><label class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></label></a>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    });
                    tabla += '</tbody></table>';

            $("#order").html(tabla);

        }

        function cleaner(codigo) {

            data = $.parseJSON('{"datos": ['+$("#json").val()+']}');
            data.datos.splice(codigo-1,1);

            $("#json").val(JSON.stringify(data).substring(10, ((JSON.stringify(data).length)-2)));
            if($("#json").val() != ''){
                invoice($("#json").val());
            }else{
                invoice($("#json").val());
                $('#total').html('0.00');
                $("#send_orden").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        }

        function editar(codigo,num) {
            $("#agregar").hide();
            $("#editar").show();
            data = $.parseJSON('{"datos": ['+$("#json").val()+']}');

            $.each(data.datos, function (i, item) {
                if(item.codigo == codigo){
                    $("#productos").val(item.descripcion);
                    $("#codigo_p").val(item.codigo);
                    $("#descri_p").val(item.descripcion);
                    $("#precio_p").val(item.precio_unidad);
                    $("#cantidad_p").val(item.cantidad);
                    $("#num_p").val(num);
                }
            });
            $("#order").addClass('disabledbutton');
        }
</script>
@endsection
```

Aqui el controlador de Ordenes:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class OrdenesController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
   //$this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{

    $id =  \App\CabOc::where('codigo','=', \Auth::user()->getPhysicalDeliveryOfficeName())
                ->where('camp','=', $this->CampActual())
                ->first();

    if(isset($id)){
        $orden = \App\DetOc::find($id->id);
        $detalles = \App\CabOc::find($id->id)->detalles;

        $results = collect([]);

        foreach ($detalles as $detalle) {
            $ps = \App\ArticPrecios::find($detalle->cod_art)->artic;

            $prs = \App\ArticPrecios::select('precio')->where('camp','=', $this->CampActual())
                            ->where('anio','=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y'))
                            ->where('codigo','=', $detalle->cod_art)
                            ->first();

            $results->push( [
                    //'id_orden' => $detalle->id,
                    'codigo' => $detalle->cod_art,
                    'descripcion' => trim($ps->descripcion),
                    'precio_unidad' => $prs->precio,
                    'cantidad' => $detalle->cantidad,
                    'subtotal_item' => ($prs->precio * $detalle->cantidad),                        
                    ] );

        }
        return view('ordenes')->with(['CampActual' => $this->CampActual(), 'encabezado' => $orden->orden, 'detalles' => $results ]);
    }

    return view('ordenes')->with('CampActual', $this->CampActual());

}
```

}

Comment: Deberías dar mas informacion del codigo, la vista para ver como le estas haciendo el llamado a los enlaces, sus controladores y los metodos, a simple vista pareciera que no estas evaluando los enlaces para que te permita ingresar si estas autenticado... pero sin la informacion necesaria no se podria dar una respuesta concreta.

Comment: J. Rivera gracias por responder, agregue mas información al post inicial, no he podido solucionar aun. Saludos

Comment: No estoy muy seguro Mixzplit porque no he usado ese paquete pero pareciera que el problema esta en el middleware, debe tener en algun lado una condicion que te redirecciona al login, revisa el middleware para ver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revisando todo mi codigo y sobre todo el componente AdLdap para conectarme a Active Directory, resolvi mi problema.

El problema estaba en una propiedad de adldap.php

```
   'auto_connect' => true,
```

Esta propiedad estaba en false y aunque autenticaba con el dominio AD al logear perdía su conexión y al linkear en algún menú es como si no hubiese autenticado, es decir la sesión no persistía por alguna razón, asi que haciendo pruebas, cambie esta propiedad y soluciono mi problema.

Gracias a los que intentaron ayudar.

Saludos